# Background-position: center center alternatives or synonyms for SVG or CSS in SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am working on a website where I have an SVG that covers a div. If I set this SVG as a `background-image` and then apply `background-position: center center`, it works as intended. On smaller screen sizes, it zooms in to its center. However, my problem is that I can't apply any additional CSS in this way.

It's possible to get the same effect what `background-position: center center` does, but without `background-image`. I was trying the `object-fit:cover; object-position:center center` but it's not worked.

This works well

```
<div
  style="background-image: {{asset('assets/vectors/bg.svg')}}; height: 100vh; background-position:center center"
>
```

But I want it to work in this way, achieving exactly the same effect.

```
<div>
  <svg>     /* So I can apply additional css on it */
</div
```

Comment: Please read about [preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio). It may be what you need. In order to center the svg you may try `"xMidYMid slice"`

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thank for information! Never heard about this attribute before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this behavior you have to set the SVG attribute `preserveAspectRatio` to the value `xMidYMid slice` like follows:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
    <!-- your code here -->
</svg>
```

The part `xMidYMid` of this value means that your SVG will be placed in the *middle* by `X` and `Y` coordinations from view box.

The part `slice` of this value means that your SVG will be sliced if it not fits the same position and size like its view box.

Read more about this attribute in this tutorial: [Understanding SVG Coordinate Systems and Transformations](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/)